# No LOB datatypes in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We are working on Oracle to Redshift migration project.
As part of migration, we have requirement to create a CLOB value supported column in Redshift.
We have tried in many ways to find out a data type that is similar to CLOB of Oracle.
But unfortunately we are not successful.

We have a max size of 171,000 character length in Oracle CLOB column and that needs to be moved into Redshift.

Can anyone please suggest if we have any way to create a column with CLOB kind of datatype in Redshift?
Also please let me know if we have an alternate datatype for BLOB as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html) says

> AWS DMS converts BLOBs, CLOBs, and NCLOBs to a VARCHAR on the target Amazon Redshift instance. Amazon Redshift doesn't support VARCHAR data types larger than 64 KB, so **you can't store traditional LOBs on Amazon Redshift**.

[Furthermore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html), you can store up to 65535 bytes into a "CHAR" datatype column:

| Name | Storage | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VARCHAR, CHARACTER VARYING, or NVARCHAR | 4 bytes + total bytes for characters, where each character can be 1 to 4 bytes | **65535 bytes** (64K -1) |

Therefore, it looks as if you'll have to **split** that `CLOB` into 3 columns, e.g.

```
TEXT_1 VARCHAR(65000),
TEXT_2 VARCHAR(65000),
TEXT_3 VARCHAR(65000)
```

and put *substrings* into them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.
We are usually using Copy command to copy the data into Redshift tables.
Can you please let us know if we have any specific keyword/clause in COPY command to split a CLOB column and insert it into the REDSHIFT table's different columns?
If yes, please let us know.