# Oracle CLOB data type to Redshift data type

Tags: oracle, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, database-migration

we are in the process of migrating Oracle tables to redshift tables. We found that few tables are having CLOB data type. In redshift we converted CLOB to Varchar(65535) type. While doing copy command , we are getting

> The length of the data column investigation_process is longer than the length defined in the table. Table: 65000, Data: 90123.

Which data type we need to use? Please share your suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No LOB datatypes in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738418/no-lob-datatypes-in-redshift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift isn't designed to store CLOB (or BLOB) data.  Most databases that do store the CLOB separately from the table contents to not burden all queries with the excess data.  A CLOB reference is stored in the table contents and a replacement of CLOB for reference is performed at result generation.

CLOBs should be stored in S3 and references to the appropriate CLOB (S3 key) stored in the Redshift table.  The issue is that there isn't a prepackaged tool for doing the CLOB for reference replacement with Redshift AFAIK.  Your solution will need some retooling to perform this replacement actions for all data users.  It's doable, it's just going to take a data layer that performs the needed replacement.